# Compare JSON Values and identify the differences -Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to compare the set of two JSON values for every transaction and extract specific values from the below.. I want to extract the following values cCode,dCode,hcps and mod..Can you please guide me on the snowflake SQL syntax for the same.. The first JSON is done by coder and the second json by auditor

```
1st json
[
  {
    "cCode": "7832",
    "Date": "08/26/2020",
    "ID": "511",
    "description": "holos",
    "dgoses": [
      {
        "description": "disease",
        "dCode": "Y564",
        "CodeAllId": "8921",
        "messages": [
          ""
        ],
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "description": "acute pain",
        "dCode": "U3321",
        "CodeAllId": "33213",
        "messages": [
          ""
        ],
        "sequenceNumber": 2
      },
      {
        "description": "height",
        "dCode": "U1111",
        "CodeAllId": "33278",
        "messages": [
          ""
        ],
        "sequenceNumber": 3
      },
      {
        "description": "PIDEMIA ",
        "dCode": "H8811",
        "CodeAllId": "90000",
        "messages": [
          ""
        ],
        "sequenceNumber": 4
      }
    ],
    "familyPlan": "",
    "hcpc": 5,
    "id": "",
    "isEPS": false,
    "mod": "67",
    "originalUnitAmount": "8888",
    "type": "CHARGE",
    "unitAmount": "9000",
    "vId": "90001"
  },
  {
    "cCode": "900114",
    "Date": "08/26/2020",
    "ID": "523",
    "description": "heart valve",
    "dgoses": [
      {
        "description": "Fever",
        "dCode": "J8923",
        "CodeAllId": "892138",
        "messages": [
          ""
        ],
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      }
    ],
    "familyPlan": "",
    "hcpc": 1,
    "id": "",
    "mod": "26",
    "originalUnitAmount": "19039",
    "type": "CHARGE",
    "unitAmount": "1039",
    "vId": "5113"
  }
]

2nd JSON
[
  {
    ""cCode"": ""78832"",
    ""Date"": ""08/26/2020"",
    ""ID"": ""511"",
    ""description"": ""holos"",
    ""dgoses"": [
      {
        ""description"": ""disease"",
        ""dCode"": ""Y564"",
        ""CodeAllId"": ""8921"",
        ""messages"": [
          """"
        ],
        ""sequenceNumber"": 1
      },
      {
        ""description"": ""acute pain"",
        ""dCode"": ""U3321"",
        ""CodeAllId"": ""33213"",
        ""messages"": [
          """"
        ],
        ""sequenceNumber"": 2
      },
      {
        ""description"": ""height"",
        ""dCode"": ""U41111"",
        ""CodeAllId"": ""33278"",
        ""messages"": [
          """"
        ],
        ""sequenceNumber"": 3
      },
      {
        ""description"": ""PIDEMIA "",
        ""dCode"": ""H8811"",
        ""CodeAllId"": ""90000"",
        ""messages"": [
          """"
        ],
        ""sequenceNumber"": 4
      }
    ],
    ""familyPlan"": """",
    ""hcpc"": 8,
    ""id"": """",
    ""isEPS"": false,
    ""mod"": ""67"",
    ""originalUnitAmount"": ""8888"",
    ""type"": ""CHARGE"",
    ""unitAmount"": ""9000"",
    ""vId"": ""90001""
  },
  {
    ""cCode"": ""900114"",
    ""Date"": ""08/26/2020"",
    ""ID"": ""523"",
    ""description"": ""heart valve"",
    ""dgoses"": [
      {
        ""description"": ""Fever"",
        ""dCode"": ""J8923"",
        ""CodeAllId"": ""892138"",
        ""messages"": [
          """"
        ],
        ""sequenceNumber"": 1
      }
    ],
    ""familyPlan"": """",
    ""hcpc"": 1,
    ""id"": """",
    ""mod"": ""126"",
    ""originalUnitAmount"": ""19039"",
    ""type"": ""CHARGE"",
    ""unitAmount"": ""1039"",
    ""vId"": ""5113""
  }
]
```

And I am looking for a result as the below:

```
 Billid ctextid cCode-Coder cCode-Auditor   deletedccode    added-ccode dCode-Coder
dCode-Auditor   deleted-dcode   added-dcode hcpc-coder  hcpc-auditor    deletedhcpc addedhcpc   mod-coder   mod-auditor deletedmod  addedmod
 7111   89321   7832,900114 78832,900114    7832    78832   Y564,U3321,U1111,H8811,J8923    Y564,U3321,U41111,H8811,J8923   U1111   U41111  5,1 8,1 5   8   67,26   67,126  26  126
```

Can anyone please help me here

sql Tried

```
with cte4 as
  
(
  select info:dCode as dtcode
  from cte3, lateral flatten( input => saveinfo:dgoses )
)
select  dCode from cte4, lateral flatten( input => dtcode )
```

This gives an error straightaway for using :

I have tried the code with the SQL server version but I need to know how to map the JSON functions to the Snowflake SQL version..Can you please help here..

```
    with I as
```

(
select *,
dense_rank() over (order by Billid, Ctextid) as tid,
dense_rank() over (partition by Billid, Ctextid order by Created) as n
from ##input1
),
D as
(
select I.*, mk.[key] as mk, m.*, dk.[key] as dk, d.*
from I
cross apply openjson(info) mk
cross apply openjson(mk.value) with
(
cCode nvarchar(max) '$.cCode',
dgoses nvarchar(max) '$.dgoses' as json
) m
cross apply openjson(dgoses) dk
cross apply openjson(dk.value) with
(
dCode nvarchar(max) '$.dCode'
) d
),
C as
(
select * from D where n = 1
),
A as
(
select * from D where n = 2
)
select
Billid,
codedby,
Ctextid,

```
 (
     select string_agg(cCode, ',') within group (order by mk)
     from 
     (
         select distinct cCode, mk
         from C
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as cCodeCoder,
 (
     select string_agg(cCode, ',') within group (order by mk)
     from 
     (
         select distinct cCode, mk
         from A
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as cCodeAuditor,
 (
     select string_agg(cCode, ',')
     from
     (
         select cCode
         from C
         where tid = t.tid
         except
         select cCode
         from A 
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as deletedcCode,
 (
     select string_agg(cCode, ',')
     from
     (
         select cCode
         from A
         where tid = t.tid
         except
         select cCode
         from C
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as addedcCode,

 (
     select string_agg(dCode, ',') within group (order by mk, dk)
     from 
     (
         select distinct dCode, mk, dk
         from C
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as dCodeCoder,
 (
     select string_agg(dCode, ',') within group (order by mk, dk)
     from 
     (
         select distinct dCode, mk, dk
         from A
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as dCodeAuditor,
 (
     select string_agg(dCode, ',')
     from
     (
         select dCode
         from C
         where tid = t.tid
         except
         select dCode
         from A 
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as deleteddCode,
 (
     select string_agg(dCode, ',')
     from
     (
         select dCode
         from A
         where tid = t.tid
         except
         select dCode
         from C
         where tid = t.tid
     ) d
 ) as addeddCode
```

from I as t
where n = 1

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: What's your table structure? Are they in the same row in two different columns? Your second JSON has extra double quotes. That won't parse in a JSON variant, so is that an artifact in copying?

Comment: @GregPavlik: Sorry there are no double quotes in the second JSON..I have edited the same in the question..The json's are in two different rows...The table structure is Billid(int),Ctextid(int),info(Json),created(timestamp),createdby.(varchar)...the first json is created by coder at a earlier created time and the second JSON is created by the auditor at a later created time..The second JSON(by auditor) is the correct and final one among the two...The 2 jsons are present for every pair of Billid and ctextid..The JSON's are present in the info column

Comment: Any inputs here would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you need the data, but you're trying to get "cCode, dCode, hcps and mod" (assuming hcps is actually hcpc). The problem is cCode, hcpc, and mod are all on the same level of the JSON. dCode is not. It's nested one layer down from the other properties and is a one to many relationship. This could be flattened out to two tables with a 1:MANY relationship, or it could be flattened out in a single table repeating the cCode, hcpc, and mod values. This example shows the second option:

```
-- I created a table named FOO and added your JSON as a variant
create temp table foo(v variant);

with
JSON(C_CODE, DGOSES, HCPC, "MOD") as
(
select   "VALUE":cCode::int         as C_CODE
        ,"VALUE":dgoses             as DGOSES
        ,"VALUE":hcpc::int          as HCPS
        ,"VALUE":mod::int           as "MOD"
from foo, lateral flatten(v)
)
select C_CODE, HCPC, "MOD", "VALUE":dCode::string as D_CODE
from JSON, lateral flatten(DGOSES);
```

This creates a table like this:

```
C_CODE    HCPC    MOD    D_CODE
  7832       5     67    Y564
  7832       5     67    U3321
  7832       5     67    U1111 
  7832       5     67    HBB11
900114       1     26    J8923
```

Comment: Thank you so much Greg!!..This is very helpful..I was only wondering if we could get the result like 7832,7832,7832,7832,900114  5,5,5,5,1 (67,67,67,67,26)